# XCODE / IOS - How to use exclusive extension to immediately present whatsapp (.wai, .waa, .wam)

Tags: ios, xcode, share, whatsapp

Is there any way to make work that part of the whatsapp [document interaction API](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/iphone/23559013/):

> Alternatively, if you want to show only WhatsApp in the application list (instead of WhatsApp plus any other public/*-conforming apps) you can specify a file of one of aforementioned types saved with the extension that is exclusive to WhatsApp:
>
> - images - «.wai» which is of type net.whatsapp.image
> - videos - «.wam» which is of type net.whatsapp.movie
> - audio files - «.waa» which is of type net.whatsapp.audio
>
> When triggered, WhatsApp will **immediately present** the user with the contact/group picker screen. The media will be automatically sent to a selected contact/group.

I don't really ask for a code example as I almost tried eveything, but more if someone ever successfully opened the whatsapp application WITHOUT passing through the share menu (with messenger tile, whatsapp, notepad...) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI: As I went through a lot of tests with this, I couldn't find any solution yet.

Whatsapp recognize the file extension, but cannot even read it. Once shared, when you click on it, it's written ".whatsapp audio file", nothing more (And it's not even shared directly).

I sent a email to whatsapp developper team, they said they have others problem to fix currently, so it's not even on their to do list.

Wait & see..